# What is the format of zookeeper logs?

Tags: log4j, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to understand the zookeeper logs format so that I can write a regular expression for that but I could not find any article what exactly appearing in the logs
Below is the on log line from zookeeper . Can someone help me what exactly is getting logged between  [ ] ? Is it package name / class name ? What 0.0.0.0 stands for ?

> 2017-08-08 08:13:25,635 - INFO 
>   **[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@964]** -
>   adding SASL authorization for authorizationID: samepleApp_runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find it in your config `conf/log4j.properties`.**

Take my config and log as an example.

Related config:

> log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [myid:%X{myid}] - %-5p [%t:%C{1}@%L] - %m%n

Related log:

> 2017-02-28 17:28:30,126 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@839] - Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:52466

The content between [] is `[%t:%C{1}@%L]`, you may find the meaning of `%t` liked symbols [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

**`0.0.0.0` is part of `%t`，which is the name of thread**. The related code you can find in `NIOServerCnxnFactory.java`:

```
@Override
public void configure(InetSocketAddress addr, int maxcc) throws IOException {
    configureSaslLogin();

    thread = new Thread(this, "NIOServerCxn.Factory:" + addr);
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. I have exactly same config . Does it mean "NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181" is the thread name as there is only one : in conversionPattern ? ZooKeeperServer is the class name and 839 will be line number .